# Rest - Same MediaType in response as in request

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have a web service that consumes `XML` and `JSON`. 
The output is currently always in `XML`.
Is it possible to produce the response in the same `MediaType` as the `MediaType` that was consumed?

**What i need is:**
The request is `XML`, the response is `XML` too.
The request is `JSON`, the response is `JSON` too.

**My Code:**

```
@Path("/calculate")
public class CalculationService
{
    @POST
    @Path("/magic")
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public Output calculate(Input input)
    {
        Output output = new Output();
        output.setValue1(...);
        output.setValue2(...);
        output.setValue3(...);

        return output;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the Web service delivers the response as `MediaType.APPLICATION_XML`.

The MediaType can be controlled by setting the **Accept-Header**.

By setting the value `Accept: application/json`, the response is delivered as `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON`.